# Webpack 5 import images and fonts, rewrite url in prod

Tags: javascript, webpack, less

I need to copy the image and font files to the appropriate folder in the dist directory, the problem is that in the final css file I get the wrong url path. I tried to disable url `css-loader` then files are not copied at all. Tried adding `~` to url .
I need to use `asset/resource` to copy and paste the correct path in the stylesheet. Various other outdated solutions won't work for me.

[My webpack 5 config](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-poitras-llmkt?file=/webpack.fonfig.js)

**I import file less to main.js.**

**My folder structure**

[image: MY STRUCTURE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by adding `publicPath: "."`, why is there a dot in quotes? Because I have the path `./` in the url itself, so I add a dot and I can exit the directory.

For fonts, I created a generator that creates a separate folder, paths work on the same principle.

```js
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    publicPath: ".",
    assetModuleFilename: "./img/[name].[ext]",
    clean: true,
  },
  
  {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
        type: "asset/resource",
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/i,
        type: "asset/resource",
        generator: {
          filename: "./fonts/[name][ext]",
        },
      },
```

Answer (score 1):

Customize the [publicPath](https://webpack.js.org/guides/public-path/) to point to the folder from where your static files are served.

Comment: Even if the link can answer, can you explain why and how this can help ? At first time, it doesn't seems to very well answer